# Multi pages table with tabularx

Tags: tabularx

I'm struggling trying to divide a big table in two different pages with tabularx environment. I tried in different ways but without any good result. Any Idea?

```
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs} %
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Add caption}
\begin{center}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXX}
            \toprule
            Caratteristiche & Parametri & Strumento & Finalità  \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{3}*{Qualità}
            & Rischio dei debitori & Analisi della performace delle attività: rischio di insolvenza, ritardo nei pagamenti, perdite, recuperi & La trasparenza sulla rischiosità degli attivi ceduti consente di classificare agevolmente il rischio del portafoglio e monitorarne l'evoluzione.  \\
            \midrule            
             & Stabilità dei flussi di cassa e capacità di generare reddito & Analisi delle voci che alimentano i fondi generati dagli attivi ceduti (clausole di revoca e rinnovabilità, flussi di rimborso, realizzo delle garanzie) e comparazione con i flussi da destinare ai titoli. & Precisa e attendibile stima della distribuzione dei flussi di cassa attesi consente di: emettere titoli ABS con un elevato grado di omogeneità; provvedere prontamente al servizio sui titoli \\
            \midrule
             & Numero e consistenza degli attivi & Analisi granularità di portafoglio e incidenza di ogni attivo sull'ammontare cartolarizzato.  & Equilibrare il \textit{trade-off} tra costi di transazione, economie di scala sui costi fissi e concentrazione del rischio di credito \\
            \midrule
            Diversificazione & Settore, localizzazione geografica e vita residua degli asset \vspace{0.3cm}\newline Tipo di \textit{originator} & Emissione di multi tranche, con diverse scadenze e rendimenti, anche variabili nel tempo, coerenti al profilo di rischio-rendimento dei sotto-portafogli &Consente di controllare il rischio specifico e impatta positivamente sul rating. Costituisce un elemento di complessità nella valutazione del rischio.\\
            \midrule
            Omogeneità & Piano di rimborso \vspace{0.3cm}\newline Rendimento degli attivi \newline Scadenza attesa degli attivi & Aggregazione di attività omogenee & L'individuazione di asset sufficientemente omogenei per profili di reddito permette di costruire con maggiore precisione il rimborso degli ABS.\\
            \midrule
            Liquidabilità & Scadenza dei pagamenti & Alta frequenza e regolarità delle riscossioni & Fruire di una costante disponibilità di cassa \\
            \midrule
            Profilo giuridico & Titolarità degli attivi & Separazione giuridica degli attivi dal patrimonio del cedente & L'effettivo smobilizzo del portafoglio dal bilancio consente di liberare l'originator dal relativo rischio di credito \\
            \bottomrule
        %   Rischio dei debitori & Analisi della performace delle attività: rischio di insolvenza, ritardo nei pagamenti, perdite, recuperi & La trasparenza sulla rischiositòà degli attivi ceduti consente di classificare agevolmente il rischio del portafoglio e monitorarne l'evoluzione.  \\
            %       \cmidrule{2-4}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & Stabilità dei flussi di cassa e capicità di fenerare reddito & Analisi delle voci che alimentano i fondi generati dagli attivi ceduti (clausole di revoca e rinnovabilità, flussi di rimborso, realizzo delle garanzie) e comparazione con i fluussi da destinare ai titoli. & Precisa e attendivile stima della distribuzione dei flussi di cassa attesi consente di: emettere titoli ABS con un elevato grado di omogeneità; provvedere prontamente al servizio sui titoli \\
            \end{tabularx}%
    \end{center}
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question: needless to load `tabularx` if you load `ltablex`. And, in case the calculated  `X` columns width is oversized for the real contents of one of the columns, this width will a  maximum width. To keep having the old behaviour, you should add the `\keepXColumns` directive.

Answer (score 1):

`ltablex` will, just as `longtable` not work with tables inside a floating `table` environment. The corrected code would be the following, resulting in the table to be split onto two pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXX}
        \caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel}
        \endfirsthead
            \toprule
            Caratteristiche & Parametri & Strumento & Finalità  \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{3}*{Qualità}
            & Rischio dei debitori & Analisi della performace delle attività: rischio di insolvenza, ritardo nei pagamenti, perdite, recuperi & La trasparenza sulla rischiosità degli attivi ceduti consente di classificare agevolmente il rischio del portafoglio e monitorarne l'evoluzione.  \\
            \midrule            
             & Stabilità dei flussi di cassa e capacità di generare reddito & Analisi delle voci che alimentano i fondi generati dagli attivi ceduti (clausole di revoca e rinnovabilità, flussi di rimborso, realizzo delle garanzie) e comparazione con i flussi da destinare ai titoli. & Precisa e attendibile stima della distribuzione dei flussi di cassa attesi consente di: emettere titoli ABS con un elevato grado di omogeneità; provvedere prontamente al servizio sui titoli \\
            \midrule
             & Numero e consistenza degli attivi & Analisi granularità di portafoglio e incidenza di ogni attivo sull'ammontare cartolarizzato.  & Equilibrare il \textit{trade-off} tra costi di transazione, economie di scala sui costi fissi e concentrazione del rischio di credito \\
            \midrule
            Diversificazione & Settore, localizzazione geografica e vita residua degli asset \vspace{0.3cm}\newline Tipo di \textit{originator} & Emissione di multi tranche, con diverse scadenze e rendimenti, anche variabili nel tempo, coerenti al profilo di rischio-rendimento dei sotto-portafogli &Consente di controllare il rischio specifico e impatta positivamente sul rating. Costituisce un elemento di complessità nella valutazione del rischio.\\
            \midrule
            Omogeneità & Piano di rimborso \vspace{0.3cm}\newline Rendimento degli attivi \newline Scadenza attesa degli attivi & Aggregazione di attività omogenee & L'individuazione di asset sufficientemente omogenei per profili di reddito permette di costruire con maggiore precisione il rimborso degli ABS.\\
            \midrule
            Liquidabilità & Scadenza dei pagamenti & Alta frequenza e regolarità delle riscossioni & Fruire di una costante disponibilità di cassa \\
            \midrule
            Profilo giuridico & Titolarità degli attivi & Separazione giuridica degli attivi dal patrimonio del cedente & L'effettivo smobilizzo del portafoglio dal bilancio consente di liberare l'originator dal relativo rischio di credito \\
            \bottomrule
%           Rischio dei debitori & Analisi della performace delle attività: rischio di insolvenza, ritardo nei pagamenti, perdite, recuperi & La trasparenza sulla rischiositòà degli attivi ceduti consente di classificare agevolmente il rischio del portafoglio e monitorarne l'evoluzione.  \\
%                   \cmidrule{2-4}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & Stabilità dei flussi di cassa e capicità di fenerare reddito & Analisi delle voci che alimentano i fondi generati dagli attivi ceduti (clausole di revoca e rinnovabilità, flussi di rimborso, realizzo delle garanzie) e comparazione con i fluussi da destinare ai titoli. & Precisa e attendivile stima della distribuzione dei flussi di cassa attesi consente di: emettere titoli ABS con un elevato grado di omogeneità; provvedere prontamente al servizio sui titoli \\
            \end{tabularx}%

\end{document}
```

In order to avoid huge blanks inbetween the words, I would suggest to set the text in the table cells raggedright instead of justified. Additionally, you might want to consider altering the widths of the `X` columns for a more uniform row height:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\hsize=0.75\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}YY>{\hsize=1.25\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}Y}
        \caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel}
        \endfirsthead
            \toprule
            Caratteristiche & Parametri & Strumento & Finalità  \\
            \midrule
            Qualità
            & Rischio dei debitori & Analisi della performace delle attività: rischio di insolvenza, ritardo nei pagamenti, perdite, recuperi & La trasparenza sulla rischiosità degli attivi ceduti consente di classificare agevolmente il rischio del portafoglio e monitorarne l'evoluzione.  \\
            \midrule            
             & Stabilità dei flussi di cassa e capacità di generare reddito & Analisi delle voci che alimentano i fondi generati dagli attivi ceduti (clausole di revoca e rinnovabilità, flussi di rimborso, realizzo delle garanzie) e comparazione con i flussi da destinare ai titoli. & Precisa e attendibile stima della distribuzione dei flussi di cassa attesi consente di: emettere titoli ABS con un elevato grado di omogeneità; provvedere prontamente al servizio sui titoli \\
            \midrule
             & Numero e consistenza degli attivi & Analisi granularità di portafoglio e incidenza di ogni attivo sull'ammontare cartolarizzato.  & Equilibrare il \textit{trade-off} tra costi di transazione, economie di scala sui costi fissi e concentrazione del rischio di credito \\
            \midrule
            Diversificazione & Settore, localizzazione geografica e vita residua degli asset \vspace{0.3cm}\newline Tipo di \textit{originator} & Emissione di multi tranche, con diverse scadenze e rendimenti, anche variabili nel tempo, coerenti al profilo di rischio-rendimento dei sotto-portafogli &Consente di controllare il rischio specifico e impatta positivamente sul rating. Costituisce un elemento di complessità nella valutazione del rischio.\\
            \midrule
            Omogeneità & Piano di rimborso \vspace{0.3cm}\newline Rendimento degli attivi \newline Scadenza attesa degli attivi & Aggregazione di attività omogenee & L'individuazione di asset sufficientemente omogenei per profili di reddito permette di costruire con maggiore precisione il rimborso degli ABS.\\
            \midrule
            Liquidabilità & Scadenza dei pagamenti & Alta frequenza e regolarità delle riscossioni & Fruire di una costante disponibilità di cassa \\
            \midrule
            Profilo giuridico & Titolarità degli attivi & Separazione giuridica degli attivi dal patrimonio del cedente & L'effettivo smobilizzo del portafoglio dal bilancio consente di liberare l'originator dal relativo rischio di credito \\
            \bottomrule
%           Rischio dei debitori & Analisi della performace delle attività: rischio di insolvenza, ritardo nei pagamenti, perdite, recuperi & La trasparenza sulla rischiositòà degli attivi ceduti consente di classificare agevolmente il rischio del portafoglio e monitorarne l'evoluzione.  \\
%                   \cmidrule{2-4}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & Stabilità dei flussi di cassa e capicità di fenerare reddito & Analisi delle voci che alimentano i fondi generati dagli attivi ceduti (clausole di revoca e rinnovabilità, flussi di rimborso, realizzo delle garanzie) e comparazione con i fluussi da destinare ai titoli. & Precisa e attendivile stima della distribuzione dei flussi di cassa attesi consente di: emettere titoli ABS con un elevato grado di omogeneità; provvedere prontamente al servizio sui titoli \\
            \end{tabularx}%

\end{document}
```