# Convenient handling of full-width multi-page tables in two-column documents?

Tags: tables, formatting, longtable

Lately, I was trying to fit a long multi-column table with a lot of text in a double-column single-file document. The document is making heavy use of single-column `tabularx`s in two-column mode, my long table is in one-column mode. I struggled in conveniently getting the multi-page table to work with `tabularx`-like column formatting up to page-width.

As for the **convenience/automation part** (thanks to the [nice overview](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12672/which-tabular-packages-do-which-tasks-and-which-packages-conflict/12673#12673)), I know of

- `tabularx`, awesome for column formatting **but** not for multi-page tables
- `ltablex`, awesome for combining `tabularx` with `longtable` **but** not well matching with double-column documents (at least I haven't managed to get around the changes `ltablex` does to the `tabularx` package)
- `xtab` (enhancement of `supertabular`), awesome features **but** without supporting `tabularx`-style column formatting (at least I haven't managed)
- `tabulary`, which nicely automates column formatting **but** is [not the right thing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78075/multi-page-with-tabulary) to do multi-page tables

I found some answers on multi-page tables with `tabularx` (e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427070/multi-pages-table-with-tabularx), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345382/combining-tabularx-sidewaystable-and-longtable)) and an answer using `tabulary` ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78075/multi-page-with-tabulary)), not quite doing what I intent.

The following MWE using `ltablex` does almost what I want:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \usepackage{tabularx} % works for 1st table only
\usepackage{ltablex} % works for 2nd table only

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{table}
  \caption{A small table in twocolumn mode}
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{lllXX}
    \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C4} & \textbf{C5} \\ 
    A & 1 & a & Quite a bit of text here as well, though. & Quite a bit of text here as well, though. \\
    A & 1 & a & Quite a bit of text here as well, though. & Quite a bit of text here as well, though. 
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\newpage
\onecolumn
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l>{\hsize.2\hsize}XXX}
  \caption{Full-width multi-page table in one-column mode}\\
  \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C4} \\
  \endfirsthead
  \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C4} \\
  \endhead
  \multicolumn{4}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ 
  \endfoot
  \multicolumn{4}{r}{{End}} \\
  \endlastfoot
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] \\
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] \\
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] \\
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] \\
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] \\
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] 
\end{tabularx}

\newpage
\twocolumn
\lipsum[10-14]
\end{document}
```

The MWE works with either the first table and `tabularx` or the second table and `ltablex`. However, with `ltablex` (which uses `longtable`), I am getting:

```
Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode.
```

Also, I got aware of the `ltxtable` package, however, it requires a split of files. Can I get `ltablex` to deal better with twocolumn mode or do I have to switch to `ltxtable`?

Thank you!

Comment: You can insert `tabularx` in a `strip` environment from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle).

Comment: it isn't clear how you want the page breaking to work, it seems that you do not want the table to be broken at each column, but rather have a full width table with breaking at page rather than column level, in which case the two-column nature of the rest of the document shouldn't be an issue just put `\onecolumn` before the table and do as you would do for a single column document. that said I think `tabularx` is over-used and I probably wouldn't use it on a document I was writing by hand in latex (it is more useful for automated production where you have less control over the formatting)

Comment: @David: Thank you. I am actually talking of a situation where `\onecolumn` is already in place. I will make this clear in the question. As `ltablex` came closest to what I wanted but was interfering AND I wanted to keep my other `tabularx` chunks, I was wondering whether there is a package/a way to do it without this sort of conflict? I read that `ltablex` has a `\setlongtable` switch. Believing that this would change `ltablex`'s mode of using `longtable` and `tabularx` I tried to set it but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Of course, not using `tabularx` in the first place would be an option.

Comment: Really you should (always) provide a small complete test document that shows the problem, I can not guess what "interference" you mean, do you get an error messgage or wrong output or .... ? If you add a test document to your question it would be much easier to debug.

Comment: @Mario given the time it takes to write a document, spending a few seconds to choose the column widths in a table seems to me time worth spending, why do you need `tabularx` ?

Comment: @David: I have used tabularx already, didn't have enough time to convert the code of all tables. In principle, I understand your suggestion perfectly. I will provide an MWE asap. Awk.

Comment: not really a problem, you could leave all your tabularx, and just change the markup for the multipage table,  ltxtable would work for you, or you could use a normal longtable for that table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82238/discussion-between-mario-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: What is the purpose of  "{l>{\hsize.2\hsize}XXX}"? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, afaik, for telling LaTeX that the 2nd column should be stretched to a width of `0.2 \hsize`. Without that the three variable-width columns (specified with X) would be split evenly, that is, `1/3 \hsize` each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a recent package [`xltabular`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xltabular) making it possible to have all code in a single file, getting rid of interferences of `ltablex` with (floats in) two-column mode while introducing some convenience over `longtable`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx} % works for 1st table only
\usepackage{xltabular} % works for 2nd table only

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{table}
  \caption{A small table in twocolumn mode}
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{lllXX}
    \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C4} & \textbf{C5} \\ 
    A & 1 & a & Quite a bit of text here as well, though. & Quite a bit of text here as well, though. \\
    A & 1 & a & Quite a bit of text here as well, though. & Quite a bit of text here as well, though. 
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\newpage
\onecolumn
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{l>{\hsize.2\hsize}XXX}
  \caption{Full-width multi-page table in one-column mode}\\
  \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C4} \\
  \endfirsthead
  \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C4} \\
  \endhead
  \multicolumn{4}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ 
  \endfoot
  \multicolumn{4}{r}{{End}} \\
  \endlastfoot
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] \\
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] \\
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] \\
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] \\
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] \\
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] 
\end{xltabular}

\newpage
\twocolumn
\lipsum[10-14]
\end{document}
```

Thanks to David Carlisle for pointing me to that package.

Answer (score 1):

According to David's suggestion I modified my MWE to be:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx} % works for 1st table only
\usepackage{ltxtable} % works for 2nd table only

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{table}
  \caption{A small table in twocolumn mode}
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{lllXX}
    \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C4} & \textbf{C5} \\ 
    A & 1 & a & Quite a bit of text here as well, though. & Quite a bit of text here as well, though. \\
    A & 1 & a & Quite a bit of text here as well, though. & Quite a bit of text here as well, though. 
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\newpage
\onecolumn
\LTXtable{\linewidth}{table.tex}

\newpage
\twocolumn
\lipsum[10-14]
\end{document}
```

with the table in an extra file `table.tex`:

```
\begin{longtable}{l>{\hsize.2\hsize}XXX}
  \caption{Full-width multi-page table in one-column mode}\\
  \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C4} \\
  \endfirsthead
  \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C4} \\
  \endhead
  \multicolumn{4}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ 
  \endfoot
  \multicolumn{4}{r}{{End}} \\
  \endlastfoot
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] \\
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] \\
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] \\
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] \\
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] \\
  Text & Some other text here & \lipsum[11] & \lipsum[11] 
\end{longtable}
```

This is a decent solution, if we accept to split the document into two files.